# Form submit redirect not working using Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I'm using the [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin on my Wordpress site and I found a method to redirect the form to another URL from the documentation on [this page](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/).

I tried adding the following code to the additional settings field on my form:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

I tested this on [my website](http://dg.mems.com/) at the top of the page via the 'Request a quote' button and submitted. Unfortunately no redirect is forced.

Why is this feature not working? I'm using the form within the lightbox (this could be the reason), but I need to redirect to the homepage when you submit the form as it is a 'one-page' website.

Please feel free to test for yourselves, I only receive the test emails anyway at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I have a very simple solution:

Just add this to the first of the Messages fields in the Contact form, the one titled: "# Sender's message was sent successfully":

Your message was sent successfully.

```
<script>window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';</script>
```

Comment: @Tim 
try this the previous code has some errors

<script>window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';</script>
Now i have edited my answer.

Comment: I had written this code for an old version of Wordpress CF plugin, Not sure its working for the current version.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script> window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`on_sent_ok: setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = 'URL_TO';}, 1000);`

this one works fine on me... plus the delay time... 1000 = 1 sec

Comment: Worked for me too, but delay time 1sec is too high because I observed once the form is submitted, people either close the page or moves to some other tab before it takes them to the next page. So my opinion is to reduce the delay by 200ms

Answer (score 1):

on_sent_ok has been replaced in the latest versions with event-based redirection.

Reference: https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

```
    <script>
     document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        location = 'http://example.com/';
     }, false );
    </script>
```

Change http://example.com to the URL you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Contact Form 7 - Success Page Redirects plugin. Very simple to use, works very well.

Comment: Using this plugin captcha disappears from the page. And page shows error because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('/thank-you');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Still `on_sent_ok:` is not working  please add below code in your js file.

```
 if ($('.wpcf7-form.sent').length) {
      $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.example.com')
    }
```